# Android onTouchListeners for seperate views

Tags: android

I am trying to drag and drop views around on my screen.  I have an array of views and id like to set an on click listener for each one so that I know which piece the user is trying to interact with.  For some reason the listener will only set to whichever piece is placed last, and from there behaves like i want it too.  How do I make it so that each view has its own individual on click handler.

Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val touch = TouchListener()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val mainScreen = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rellayout)

    for ( i in 0 .. 4)
    {
        for (j in 0 .. 4)
        {
            val testSquare = Square(this, (1+2*i)*54f , (1+2*j)*54f, (PI/4).toFloat())

            testSquare.setOnTouchListener(touch)
            mainScreen.addView(testSquare)
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I have also tried setting the on touch listener inside the loop so that it instantiates on each pass through but it gave the same result

Comment: Your code is correct, as far as setting the listener on each `View`. I suspect that at least part of the problem is that all of those `Square`s might be overlapping, since you're adding them to a `RelativeLayout` with no `LayoutParams` and rules to have them laid out otherwise. If that's the case, then it would seem like the last one is the only one that gets the listener set correctly, because it's the only one receiving touch events, since it's on top.

Answer (score 0):

you can implements onTochListener then switch in different view like this.

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnTouchListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_)
    val mainScreen = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rellayout)

    for ( i in 0 .. 4)
    {
        for (j in 0 .. 4)
        {
            val testSquare = Square(this, (1+2*i)*54f , (1+2*j)*54f, (PI/4).toFloat())

            testSquare.setOnTouchListener(this)
            mainScreen.addView(testSquare)
        }
    }
}

override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.death // these are example ids
        -> {
        }
        R.id.daimajia_indicator_wrapper -> {
        }
        R.id.Accordion -> {
        }
    }//do code
    //do code
    //do code
    return false
}
```

}